# Mongodb how to use $elemMatch to limit results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My problem is: I have a structure similar to this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  participants: [
    { name: "joe", status: 0 },
    { name: "james", status: 2}
  ],
  content: "mongomongo"
}

{
  id: 2,
  participants: [
    { name: "joe", status: 1 },
    { name: "jordan", status: 3}
  ],
  content: "dongodongo"  
}
```

What I want to do is run a query with almost the same effect as this:

```
db.find({ '_id': { $in: someArray}}, { participants: {$elemMatch: {'name': someName }}}
```

I would specify an array of object IDs for the $in, and then I would provide an username. What happens is that it would give me back both objects, but the participants array only has the entry that the $elemMatch found:

```
{
  id: 1,
  participants: [
    { name: "joe", status: 0 }
  ]
}

{
  id: 2,
  participants: [
    { name: "joe", status: 1 }
  ]
}
```

This is what I want, but the part that I DON'T want is that it leaves out other fields (namely `content`). How can I adjust the query so it that still returns one field in the participants array, but also returns the other fields such as content?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually found the solution to my question. Just had to tweak the original query I used. I had confused the projection field and the options field since I was using Mongoose to manage mongodb interactions.

Here's the query that works:

```
db.find({ '_id': { $in: someArray}}, { participants: {$elemMatch: {'name': someName }}, content: 1, [anything] : 1});
```

Comment: Well Done. This is what I was trying to get at in the last edit to my answer. Just add any more fields you want returned to the projection argument. :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood the original post and example. If the only other field you are worried about returning is 'content', then you could add it to the *projection* argument like so:

```
db.collection.find(
    { 
        '_id': { 
            $in: someArray
        }
    },
    {
        'participants': {
            $elemMatch: {
                'name': someName 
            }
        },
        'content' : 1
    }
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need to return all the fields, not just the filtered participants array

Comment: Sorry @Xinzz I misunderstood your original question. See my edit above. I believe the problem was just that your query was off a bit in your original example.

Comment: I actually tried this one as well... It returns all fields, including everything in the participants array, not just the entry in the array that has `someName`

Comment: RIGHT! I get it now. The way you were using $elemMatch before inside of the _projection_ argument was correct. That is how you project portions of arrays properly. Apologies for that. Are there more fields other than 'content' that you also need to return? Because you could just add 'content: 1' to the project argument underneath 'participants' and it would return both the filtered participants array and 'content'